# How to make div's inside div responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I know there are millions of similar questions on the related subject and i've read many of them, but somehow i still don't really get how to position div's or different things based on the media.

So here's the thing. I have a div, which has 4 different div's that are basically just 4 different social-bar pictures. I would like to make them responsive to all media, but most importantly to mobile.

If there's anyone kind enough who could teach me step by step, how to do it, ill be more than happy with it.

So my code looks like this @ the moment.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-5" id="social-bar">
    <div class="pic1"></div>
    <div class="pic2"></div>
    <div class="pic3"></div>
    <div class="pic4"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#social-bar
{
float:left;
display: inline-flex;
margin-top: 60px;
}
.pic1
{
background: url('../image/facebook.png') no-repeat;
width:29px;
height:27px;
margin-left: 180px;
}
.pic2
{
background: url('../image/twitter.png') no-repeat;
width:29px;
height:27px;
margin-left: 20px;
}
.pic3
{
background: url('../image/instagram.png') no-repeat;
width:29px;
height:27px;
margin-left: 20px;
}
.pic4
{
background: url('../image/gmail.png') no-repeat;
width:29px;
height:27px;
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

**This is what i've tried so far, but it doesn't seem to be working**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 350px){
.pic1{
    background: url('../image/facebook.png');
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 350px){
.pic2{
    background: url('../image/twitter.png');
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 350px){
.pic3{
    background: url('../image/instagram.png');
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 350px){
.pic4{
    background: url('../image/gmail.png');
}
}
```

**This is how social bar is positioned at the moment**

[image]
**Any input will be appreciated, thank you guys!**

Comment: give width and height in percentages and give float:left

Comment: width and height of 100%? @varunaaruru

Comment: check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K6NR6/1/)

Comment: Can you create a snippet or a fiddle with the problem?

Comment: too localised - you're basically asking help with your code, any answers here won't likely help any other person.

Comment: @varunaaruru yours seems to be the best solutio with some tweeks because it kinda causes a few trouble to other positioning...just one question...on media it says display:inline ...how do you make them display inline horizontaly instead of vertically?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides you're right, i am asking for help and i don't see any crime in it. It's basically forum where u ask for help, isn't it ?

Comment: it's a forum where you are supposed to ask questions that might help other users as well - If your question was more generalized, e.g "how exactly do media queries work for mobile" with a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to illustrate the question then I guess it's fine. -  I didn't say it's a crime. As it stands now you want quick/dirty help with your current code shortcomings.

Comment: `display: inline-block;
  horizontal-align: middle;`

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides agree

Comment: Yes you are right. I'am trying to get work done dirty and that's only because i've spent last few hours trying to figure out how responsive works, but couldn't figure it out. Some learn faster i guess, but sadly i have a deadline and i seeked for help because it was driving me crazy. And no i don't like doing dirty work, i like to learn new things each day as im far from where i want to be right now. Do not worry, i will go through many pages that explain how responsive work, because i do not like leaving the job undone. Have a good day and a happy new year to you. @NicholasKyriakides

Comment: @fox Responsiveness can be done in many ways, so do you want the images to get smaller when no space or start on a new line or become a drop down or how?

Comment: eventhough i've already marked a solution, ill be happy to learn different ways if you have any suggestions. I want the images to go into new line with the width of 100%. It means that when i open page on mobile, there will be logo with the width of 100%, than the social bar with the width of 100% of the screen, and then the car button @LGSon

Comment: I will post an answer soon showing that, and luckily for me, if you find that one better you can always change your marked solution :)

Comment: @fox Now I have added my answer. Give me a note if you need to ask something more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample showing how you can do.

It have 2 media queries which kicks in when screen is less than 660px and 440px wide.

Pay attention to their order in the CSS as well. The 660px rules comes before the 440px rules, and is valid even when the 440px rules kicks in, which means that the rules made in the 660px query need to be altered again in 440px, if they should be different.

Use [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lp6oq31/) and play with the different settings, resize the window and see what happens.

*Side note:*

If you aren't used to fiddle, you can resize the inner windows by dragging their borders, which make it easy to test how the page changes. Just push the "Run" and/or "Update" in upper left corner, to reload or save the last code changes.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0
}

.header {
  min-width: 380px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}

.container {
  padding: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.header .col {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
}
.header .col:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center
}
.header .col:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: right
}

.header .col:nth-child(1) img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

.container .row {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container .row span {
  margin-left: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}


@media (max-width: 660px){

  .header .col:nth-child(1) {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
  }

  .header .col:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: left;
    width: 50%;
  }

  .header .col:nth-child(3) {
    width: 50%;
  }

  .header .col:nth-child(2) img {
    width: 20%;
    height: 30px;
  }

}

@media (max-width: 440px){

  .header .col:nth-child(1),
  .header .col:nth-child(2),
  .header .col:nth-child(3) {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    text-align: left
  }

  .header .col:nth-child(2) img {
    width: 24%;
  }

  .container .row span {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="col">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x30/?text=logo" />    
  </div><div class="col">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />    
    <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />    
    <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />    
    <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />    
  </div><div class="col">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/60x30/?text=cart butt" />    
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100/sports" />
    <span> Some text ... being aligned at the top</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100/city" />
    <span> Some text ... being aligned at the top</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: definitely seems like a better solution :) thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Read more about [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) and responsive web-design  [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/varunaaruru/K6NR6/56/)

```
<div class="abc">
<div class="bcd">
    <a href="#">
    <img class="img1" width="50" height="50"/>
    </a>
    <a><h3>Some Text</h3></a> 
</div>
<div class="bcd">
    <a href="#">
    <img class="img1" width="50" height="50"/>
    </a>
    <a><h3>Some Text</h3></a> 
</div>
<div class="bcd">
    <a href="#">
    <img class="img1" width="50" height="50"/>
    </a>
    <a><h3>Some Text</h3></a> 
</div>
<div class="bcd">
    <a href="#">
    <img class="img1" width="50" height="50"/>
    </a>
    <a><h3>Some Text</h3></a> 
</div>   
</div>


<style>
.abc{padding:0; margin:0; box-sizing:border-box; width:100%;}
.bcd{display:inline-block;width:24%;}
@media all and (max-width: 360px){
    .bcd
    {
        display:inline-block;
        width:49%;
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: @fox if you have any doubts in media-query ask me

Answer (score 1):

you can do that without using media queries by just simple CSS try this

**html code**

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
<div class="social-icons">
<a href="" target="new" title="facebook"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/yootheme/social-bookmark/48/social-facebook-box-blue-icon.png" alt="facebook" /></a>
<a href="" target="new" title="twitter"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/yootheme/social-bookmark/48/social-twitter-box-blue-icon.png" alt="twitter" /></a>
<a href="" target="new" title="instagram"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/uiconstock/socialmedia/48/Instagram-icon.png" alt="instagram" /></a>
<a href="" target="new" title="gmail" class="last"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/cornmanthe3rd/plex/48/Communication-gmail-icon.png" alt="gmail" /></a>
<div class="clr"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.social-icons a {
float: left;
margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.social-icons a img {
width: 29px;
height: 27px;
}
.clr {
clear: both;
}
.last {
margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```