# Make responsive all the content inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make responsive all the content inside a div.
The content can be dynamic (tables with paddings and/or margins, tables inside tables, div, text, etc etc). I searched a lot but I didn't find a good solution (eg: [How to make div's inside div responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34703868/how-to-make-divs-inside-div-responsive))

Doesn't matter a solution with CSS or JS. The best solution was try to add this properties to all the elements inside de div:

> width: 100vw; max-width: 100vw !important;

But doesn't work for all the cases. Can anybody help me?
Thanks you very much!

Regards

Answer (score 1):

first of all i suggest u to try `display:flex` and second one: the design can't be fully custom u must describe your problem more detailed ... i suggest to use bootstrap classes or some other grid classes... or `display:grid`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper div{
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.wrapper{
  overflow: hidden;
}
#one{
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  
}
#two{
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* ----------- iPhone 5, 5S, 5C and 5SE ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 568px) {
  #one, #two{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
/* ----------- iPhone 6, 6S, 7 and 8 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px)  and (max-device-width: 667px){
  #one, #two{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
/* ----------- iPhone 6+, 7+ and 8+ ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-width: 736px) {
  #one, #two{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
/* ----------- iPad 1, 2, Mini and Air ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  #one, #two{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
/* ----------- Samsung S8 ----------- */
@media screen and (device-width: 360px) and (device-height: 740px) {
  #one, #two{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
/* ----------- Google Nexus 6 ----------- */
@media screen and (device-width: 412px) and (device-height: 732px) {
  #one, #two{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="one">
    <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #339966;"><a href="https://alfredclouet.fr/index.php/regime-sans-lactose/product/listing/72-sans-gluten" style="color: #339966;"><span style="font-size:18px; font-weight: bold;"><span style="color: #d7901d;">Regime Sans Gluten </span><img src="https://alfredclouet.fr/images/AC-Regimes-LOGO/gluten-free.png" alt="gluten free" width="30" height="30"></span></a></span></p>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <p style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://alfredclouet.fr/index.php/regime-sans-lactose/product/listing/73-sans-lactose"><span style="color: #ffcc00; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;"><span style="color: #92d9f8;">Regime Sans Lactose </span><img src="https://alfredclouet.fr/images/AC-Regimes-LOGO/lactose-free.png" alt="lactose free" width="30" height="30"></span></a></p>
  </div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="one">
    <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #339966;"><a href="https://alfredclouet.fr/index.php/regime-sans-lactose/product/listing/72-sans-gluten" style="color: #339966;"><span style="font-size:18px; font-weight: bold;"><span style="color: #d7901d;">Regime Sans Gluten </span><img src="https://alfredclouet.fr/images/AC-Regimes-LOGO/gluten-free.png" alt="gluten free" width="30" height="30"></span></a></span></p>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <p style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://alfredclouet.fr/index.php/regime-sans-lactose/product/listing/73-sans-lactose"><span style="color: #ffcc00; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;"><span style="color: #92d9f8;">Regime Sans Lactose </span><img src="https://alfredclouet.fr/images/AC-Regimes-LOGO/lactose-free.png" alt="lactose free" width="30" height="30"></span></a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is some sample of responsive div in div.